# Is it possible to create a custom numbering scheme for endnotes?

Tags: microsoft-word

In Microsoft Word, when I add endnotes, I can choose whether they are marked by numbers, letters, roman numerals, special symbols, etc. I would like my endnotes to be numbers, but surrounded with brackets, such as: [1], [2], etc. Is there a way to do this automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but once all of your footnotes/endnotes are in the document, you can change the format using the Search/Replace functionality. See [this post at Microsoft's Tech Community](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/word/footnotes-endnotes-in-square-brackets/m-p/1933305) for more information

Comment: Here is a similar question with answers dealing with Captions. https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/47835-putting-parentheses-around-sequence-number-caption-label.html